# More perlish way to sort string with leading floating point number?

Tags: perl, sorting

I have an array of strings. Each string has multiple fields delimited by a pipe character. I want to do a reverse numerical sort of the strings by the first field in each string. I've written some perl code that works fine and I'm wondering if there is a more perlish way to write this.

```
sub by_firstField {
    my @tmpA = split ( /\|/, $a ) ;
    my @tmpB = split ( /\|/, $b ) ;
    if ($tmpA[0]> $tmpB[0]) { -1 } elsif ($tmpA[0] < $tmpB[0]) { 1 } else { 0 }
}

push @unsorted, ( "8.02|a|b|c", "47.6|d|e|f", "108.1|g|h|i", "411.5|j|k|l", "8.1|m|n|o" ) ;

@sorted = sort by_firstField @unsorted ;

for ( my $i = 0 ; $i <= $#sorted; $i++ ) {
    print $sorted[$i] . "\n" ;
}
```

And, here's the output:

```
411.5|j|k|l
108.1|g|h|i
47.6|d|e|f
8.1|m|n|o
8.02|a|b|c
```

Comment: Does `<=>` ring any bells?

Comment: Sure. But I still need to split the string before doing the comparison.

Comment: @Sol strictly speaking, you don't. `@sorted = reverse sort { $a <=> $b } @unsorted` produces some warnings but gives exactly the output you asked for. That's because numifying looks for a number at the beginning of the string and stops when it finds something else. Not recommended, but it's worth understanding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sort {
   my @fields_a = split /\|/, $a;
   my @fields_b = split /\|/, $b;
   $fields_b[0] <=> $fields_a[0]
}
```

or

```
sort { ( $b =~ /([^|]*)/ )[0] <=> ( $a =~ /([^|]*)/ )[0] }
```

or

```
map $_->[0],
sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] }
map [ $_, split /\|/ ],
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the education. Yep, your solutions are definitely more perlish.